# How to retrieve the app name from within my model declaration

Tags: django

In my application `pos`, I have the following model::

```
class Receipt(Model):
    class Meta:    
        db_table = 'pos_receipt'
```

I want to rename the table as `pos_receipt_ghost` and I don't want to hardcode the app name.
I want to do this:

```
class Receipt(Model):
    class Meta:    
        db_table = '%s_receipt_ghost` % get_app_name()
```

Does something like `get_app_name` exists ?

Answer (score 1):

Name of the app is available in [Meta.app_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label)

```
class Receipt(Model):
    class Meta:
        pass
Receipt._meta.db_table = '%s_receipt_ghost' % Receipt._meta.app_label
```

Or

```
class Receipt(Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = '%s_receipt_ghost'                
Receipt._meta.db_table %= Receipt._meta.app_label
```